# MySql freezes the whole program if i save, alter or try to delete a Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

im new to SQL in general, so im learning, i had many troubles before, so the code its not clean enough.

here is my trigger, its a update from all the products, generating a table in html,If you can think of another way to do it, I would love to know it to learn, initially I tried to make a cursor inside another cursor but it gave me many errors,some1 recommended to do a trigger before update to go through all the products and only use a cursor to do the checks that I need, thanks for everything <3

(Srry for my english too, hope you can understand me)

```
BEGIN

        declare contentCursor text;
        declare tableContent text default "<table width=""250"" cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0""><tbody>";
        declare alegenos varchar(30);
        declare contieneAlergenos int;
        declare trazasCerca int;
        declare siCerca text default "";

        DECLARE ch_done INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE alegenosCursor cursor for select Nombre from ps_ets_ept_alegenos;

        

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET ch_done = 1;


        -- Guardo el contenido de la descr (En los primeros 150 productos era una tabla que convertir en otra)
    -- SELECT contentCursor;
        -- Generar tabla correctamente apartir de la tabla equivocaeda
            -- Recorro una tabla con la lista de alergenos


            BLOCK2: begin
    open alegenosCursor;
                bucleAlergenos:LOOP fetch alegenosCursor into alegenos;


                IF(ch_done = 1) THEN 
                        -- handle the No data error!
                    set ch_done=1;
                END IF;
                    -- Veo si el alergeno actual lo tiene la tabla incorrecta
                    SELECT LOCATE(alegenos, old.content) into contieneAlergenos;
                    if contieneAlergenos>0 then 
                        -- En el caso de que este busco si tiene un Trazas o un Si, si me coloco al final de la palabra del alergeno, sumandole los 44 Es donde empieza el Si o el Trazas, el siete es por el largo de trazas + 1 espacio
                        SELECT LOCATE("Trazas",SUBSTR(old.content,contieneAlergenos+length(alegenos)+44,7)) INTO trazasCerca;
                        -- Si trazasCerca es mayor que 0 el contenido de ese alergeno son Trazas, asi que se lo asigno a la variable siCerca, en caso de que sea 0 le asigno un Si
                        if trazasCerca>0 then SET siCerca="Trazas";
                        else SET siCerca="Si";
                        end if;
                    
                        -- Concadeno el Si o el Trazas
                        SELECT CONCAT(tableContent,"<tr><td width=""60%"" align=""left""><strong>", alegenos, "</strong></td><td width=""40%"" align=""left""> ", siCerca, "</td></tr>") INTO tableContent; -- devuelve Alergeno y una string si tiene Trazas o si, hace falta un locate de Si o Trazas y generar la tabla
                    
                    -- En caso de no encontrar el alergeno, le meto el campo de la tabla con el alergeno y un no
                    else SELECT CONCAT(tableContent,"<tr><td width=""60%"" align=""left""><strong>", alegenos, "</strong></td><td width=""40%"" align=""left"">No</td></tr>")INTO tableContent ; -- tienes el alergeno que no está en la tabla, aqui generare la td de el alergeno con un No
                    end if;
                            
                        -- reinicio las variables que suelo concadenar
                        SET siCerca="";
                        SET trazasCerca=0;  
                        SET contieneAlergenos=0;

                         -- select tableContent as Dentro;
                END LOOP bucleAlergenos;
                    select CONCAT(tableContent,"</tbody></table>")INTO tableContent;
                    insert into pruebaTablas VALUES (tableContent);
                                                                                             set tableContent="";
                    close alegenosCursor;
            END BLOCK2; 




END
```

Comment: Please add the create through for each row parts of the trigger and confirm you are setting delimiters.

Comment: Hi! i dont know what you mean with create through for each row parts, but yes, i use DELIMITERS, and error persists

Comment: Trigger syntax is something like CREATE triggername before/after triggertype  on tablename for each row followed by trigger body - are you bypassing this using a wizard?

Comment: yes! Wanna see the generated code by wizard?

Comment: Yeas please....

Comment: `
DROP TRIGGER `pruebaTrigger`;

CREATE DEFINER=`USERNAME`@`%` TRIGGER `pruebaTrigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `ps_ets_ept_product`
FOR EACH ROW DELIMITER $$

BEGIN



END $$
DELIMITER;;



`

Comment: Well that's not right there shouldn't be a delimiter in the code block after for each row. If that is indeed what is happening then I would abandon the wizard and code on the code area. And if you typed it dpn't , what's the ui BTW?

Comment: Okay i solved without using wizard! ty so much!